# VMware/Vcenter move file from datastore to another datastore

Tags: vmware-vcenter, datastore

I have a machine template in datastore connected to one host. I want to move this template to another datastore connected to another host. They are in the same Vcenter but datastores are not connected to both hosts.

When I try to use `copy` command I got this error:

```
Cannot connect to host.
```

Can I move/copy only from/to datastores connected to the same hosts? How can I move? Should I donwload each files and upload them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to transfer files from one datastore to another both need to be connected to the same host.

You basically have three options:

1. download the files and upload them again to the new host
2. temporarily mount both datastores at the same host
3. enable SSH on both hosts (don't forget to open outgoing SSH connections in the firewall), log in via SSH on one host and copy the files via SCP to the other host.